# Using heroku with python results in http:500 error

Tags: python, http, heroku, httplib

I have a python app which pulls xml data through http. I want to run this app on Heroku. The app runs fine on Heroku if I just return "hello world" without trying to pull the xml. When I run this app locally (either by using the 'foreman' command, or just through python directly) it runs completely fine, and the "response.status" is 200, as expected. If I deploy to Heroku, it runs fine up to that point, but I get a response.status: 500 instead, and so cannot retrieve the XML data.

What might be causing this problem?

Here is the relevant function.

**Edit:**
I have tried other URLs with the same results: I get an HTTP status 200 when run locally, but 500 when run on Heroku

```
def fetchBoBXml():
  # Fetch XML info from BoB
  conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(BOB_DOMAIN, BOB_PORT)
  conn.request("GET", BOB_URL)
  response = conn.getresponse()
  status = response.status
  if status != 200:
    print "BOB response status %s" % status
    raise Exception("BoB HTTP response status: %s" % status)
  data = response.read()
  conn.close()  
  return data
```

Comment: Without knowing the URL it is harder to guess. But wouldn't you be better using [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html), instead of [`httplib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html)?

Comment: Oh sorry, the url is to a bidorbuy.co.za sellers xml api feed. It contains the username and password for bidorbuy so I didn't include it. I'll try urllib2 and see if it changes anything .I just don't understand why running the app on heroku should make a difference to an http request/response.

Comment: Why don't you use the excellent (newly 1.0) [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v1.0.0/) library instead?  Much easier

Comment: Thanks -- still haven't solved the initial problem, but requests is indeed a brilliant library

Comment: post your logs of the errors

Comment: Are you setting BOB_PORT to the environment variable PORT?